# How to integrate twitter streaming with user logins in my web page using php?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to add Twitter login and followed by their tweets in my page..
Here follows :

1. when the user clicks on twitter login, after successful authentication, the twitter api streaming should be opened and all the user tweets should be displayed day to day continuously like limiting them upto 5 or 6 tweets per day.

This was the code which i used where i could not find the solution with the twitter documentations,i want to implement this code into tweeter api streaming,

```
'<?php
require("TwitterClass.php");

## Set up the class
$username = "xxxxx";    // username
$twitter = new Twitter($username);

$lateststatus = $twitter->getLatestTweet();
echo $lateststatus;


$website = $twitter->getWebsite();
echo $website;

$backgroundimage = $twitter->getBackground();
echo $backgroundimage;

$statuses = $twitter->getTweets(5); // gets first 5 statuses
foreach($statuses as $status)
{
    $id = $status["id"];    // status ID
    $text = $status["text"];    // actual status
    $retweets = $status["retweets"];    // number of retweets
    $source = $status["source"];    // where the tweet was published from (eg tweetdeck)
    $url = $status["url"];  // status URL

    echo "<p> $text </p>";
    echo "Retweets : <a href='$url'> $retweets </a> | ";
    echo "Tweeted Via: $source ";
    echo "<br />";
}


?>'
```

Instead of giving the user name in this code i want the user to get connected with the login authentication. With this above code i could only retrieve the particular users tweets.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having problems with? Nobody will write the code for you and your scope is too wide.

Comment: If all you want is to read their tweets, you don't even need to sign in.  We use this in our site: having a username, just query twitter to get the latest tweets in json or xml format.

Comment: @AleksG yes, your right , it was the exact intention on mine, need to read the tweets of the user with username.Can you provide me any example or snippets, Regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to read the tweets for the user, you don't need to log in.  We're using a twitter widget to display the last few tweets.  Here's an approximation of our code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    new TWTR.Widget({
    version: 2,
        type: 'profile',
    rpp: 3,
        interval: 6000,
    width: 340,
    height: 200,
    theme: {
    shell: {
        background: '#FFFFFF',
    color: '#232323'
    },
    tweets: {
    background: '#FFFFFF',
        color: '#232323',
    links: '#009FB5'
    }
        },
        features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: false,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: false,
    behavior: 'all'
    }
    }).render().setUser('twitter_useranme').start();
 </script>
```

Alternatively, you can just get the details of the tweets in XML or JSON:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=twitter_username
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter_username
```

There are a few more parameters you can pass (such as max number of tweets, earliest date, etc.) - have a look at the documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: thank you,It fixed my issue.  With the above code, before can i make the user to enter his username instead of entering within the code.

Comment: @SridharSidhu Well, just put a text input on the page to enter the username, then take that username and create a URL with it.

Comment: It was fixed, thank you. 
How can i use this for my facebook custom tab, by giving the page admin access using access token permission.Can it be done.

Comment: @SridharSidhu Yes, it can be done for Facebook, but it's quite a bit more complicated.  I don't think facebook allows un-signed-in users to access timelines, so you need to implement oauth authentication to sign in and then read the data you need.  There are examples on the web - just search.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an overview](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/sign-twitter) of how to implement Sign in with Twitter.

Read, learn and them come back with any questions.

Comment: What are you having problems with exactly?